# Django problems in query

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model to access database under Django development environment. I hope to do :

```
Friends.objects.filter(pk__contains=str)[:20].filter(invite_id=77)
```

But I get this error :

```
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "D:\INSTALL\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 691
, in filter
return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\INSTALL\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 703
, in _filter_or_exclude
"Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken."
```

After querying once, I already got 20 items. Why cannot I get item by querying again?

Note: I understand the error but I want to query again. It is sure that is not a good idea, because I get the error. Who know better method?

Answer (score 1):

You have to limit the number of returned results *after* applying the filter. This is how SQL works (`WHERE` goes before `LIMIT`):

```
 Friends.objects.filter(invite_id=77)[:20]
```

Comment: This has slightly different behaviour to how I interpreted the original code. This will find the first 20 matching objects rather than all the matches in the first 20 objects. I'm not sure which what was required.

Comment: That's true, but to implement a filter after limiting the result is rather complex. Some databases can to that with a subquery, but not MySQL. The only DB independent option would be a Python-side implementation which would be expensive on the I/O and CPU side.

Comment: @KlausD.: Since it's only 20 records, there's really no need to have the database do that work.  `[f for f in Friends.objexts.all()[:20] if f.invite_id == 77]` does the trick, in the unlikely case that this is what the OP really wants.

Comment: This isn't really anything to do with the order of SQL clauses. Django builds up the SQL statement dynamically and doesn't care about the ordering of ORM calls. The problem here is simply that slicing a queryset executes the query, so you can't do any further filtering on it..